# How to see java logs inside Hyperledger Fabric chaincode?

Tags: java, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to use Fabric whith java shim and I am still searching how to display logs on the peer output ?

I tried this :

```
peer node start --logging-level DEBUG
```

also searching to use the logger of the parent class :

```
private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ChaincodeBase.class);
```

without success. Cannot see the outputs on the peer

Does anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the solution. It implies to access the Docker image inside the peer and call :

```
docker logs mycontainersidwhatever
```

but i think is could be still buggy as I am in DEBUG mode, and I see now only WARN level for the chaincode

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a new chaincode, the peer will create a new docker container called `dev-(peer name)-(contract name)-(contract version)`. You can see logs direct in this container.

However, fabric java chaincode uses its own logging configuration, and it uses an environment variable called `CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL` to define the logging level the chaincode will use. Usually, this environment variable is set to 'info' level. You can manually update the value of this variable inside the docker container running the contract, or you can define this variable into the peer, so every contract will the the defined value to it.

Answer (score 0):

In 'fabric-samples\first-network\base\peer-base.yaml' ensure you have the following before you start HLF network, and then spin up the network.

```
FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
```

This will generate logs in DEBUG mode. Now, in order to see these logs that are generated within docker contaner, we'll have to ask docker for logs, and that can be done using in a terminal window.

```
docker logs -f <<container-name>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

docker logs container_name

Or inside your docker_compose.yaml, set logging environment

FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG

Or else,

try setting up in you cli for one time use

export